# Handle SQL ExecuteNonQuery errors C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I have a table with driver's ID, name, surname, etc.

I wrote a method that gets the driver's ID from a textbox and executes a query using the `ExecuteNonQuery();` method. It retrieves the driver's data. But if the user enters an ID which isn't in the table, the Winforms get closed.

I'd like to instead show a MessageBox or something similar appear such as an error that the ID doesn't exist. How can I do that?

EDDIT

```
public string comandoSQLtxtBox(string comando)
    {
        string datosConexion = "Data Source=JNATARIO-PC;Initial Catalog= viajesDB;Integrated Security=True;";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(datosConexion))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand comandoCreartabla = new SqlCommand(comando, con);
                object scalarobject;
                scalarobject = comandoCreartabla.ExecuteScalar();
                con.Close();
                return scalarobject.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un error!");
            return "0";
        }
    }
```

I tried that way which suggested me in comments nad it partialy worked. But I've a Button that call that method "comandoSQLtxtBox" many times!, so i get almos 15 MessageBox. I tried putting this.close(); in catch but it doesn't wok (gives error). ANy tip?

THE CALLS:

```
            //------------------------------------DATOS CHOFER-----------------------------------------
        //ID chof
        string Id_chofer = sqlTools.comandoSQLtxtBox("SELECT id_chofer FROM viajes WHERE id_viaje=" + Id_viaje);
        boxIDChofViajeCurso.Text = Id_chofer;
        //Nombre chof
        boxNombreChofCurso.Text = sqlTools.comandoSQLtxtBox("SELECT nombre FROM choferes WHERE id_chofer=" + Id_chofer);
        //Apellido chof
        boxApellChofCurso.Text = sqlTools.comandoSQLtxtBox("SELECT apellido FROM choferes WHERE id_chofer=" + Id_chofer);
        //Telefono
        boxTlfChofCurso.Text = sqlTools.comandoSQLtxtBox("SELECT telefono FROM choferes WHERE id_chofer=" + Id_chofer);
        //Comentarios
        boxRichComChofCurso.Text = sqlTools.comandoSQLtxtBox("SELECT comentarios_chofer FROM choferes WHERE id_chofer=" + Id_chofer);

        //--------------------------------------DATOS AUTO-------------------------------------------
        //ID auto
        string Id_auto = sqlTools.comandoSQLtxtBox("SELECT id_auto FROM viajes WHERE id_viaje=" + Id_viaje);
        boxIDAutoCurso.Text = Id_auto;
        //Marca
        boxMarcaCurso.Text = sqlTools.comandoSQLtxtBox("SELECT marca FROM autos WHERE id_auto=" + Id_auto);
        //Modelo
        boxModeloCurso.Text = sqlTools.comandoSQLtxtBox("SELECT modelo FROM autos WHERE id_auto=" + Id_auto);
        //Patente
        boxPatenteCurso.Text = sqlTools.comandoSQLtxtBox("SELECT patente FROM autos WHERE id_auto=" + Id_auto);
        //Año
        boxAnAutoCurso.Text = sqlTools.comandoSQLtxtBox("SELECT año FROM autos WHERE id_auto=" + Id_auto);
        //Comentarios
        boxRichComAutoCurso.Text = sqlTools.comandoSQLtxtBox("SELECT comentarios_auto FROM autos WHERE id_auto=" + Id_auto);
```

Comment: can you provide code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your query in a try/catch block, and show the MessageBox in the catch. Something like, e.g.:

```
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: Minor gripe but you should be catching only SqlException in that catch block... Never catch all unless you intend to.

Comment: Second minor gripe: you should put `using(...) { ... }` blocks around the `SqlCommand`; too - not just the `SqlConnection`....

Answer (score 0):

Take your data in one Datatable and if that particular datatable has the data then it will be shown, otherwise you can use:

```
MessageBox.Show("Your Message");
```

After this you can close the `winform` by:

```
this.close();
```

Comment: Could you provide any example for taking data in one Datatble please? It'll be very useful for me. Thanks!

Comment: SqlConnection Con=new SqlConnection();
 Con.ConnectionString = "Your Connection String"
String Str = "SELECT * FROM Customer;
                    command.CommandText = Str;
                    DataTable dtdata= new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    adap.Fill(dtdata);
//You will get your data in datatable names as dtdata